# Dynamic SQL and WITH common table expression in subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, dynamic-sql

I am stuck trying to build a dynamic SQL query like the following:

```
'USE [SampleDatabase]
 DECLARE @COLUMNS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[CELL], [OFFICE]';
 WITH table_CTE (Name, DayOfBirth, Phone) AS
     (
      SELECT pp.FirstName AS Name 
            ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), pp.Birthday, 103) AS Birthday            
            ,ph.Number
      FROM Records.People pp, Records.Phones ph
          ,Records.PhoneNumberTypes pht 
      WHERE pp.PersonId = ph.PersonId AND ph.PhoneTypeId = pht.PhoneTypeId 
            AND MONTH(pp.Birthday) = 06
     )
 SELECT Name, DayOfBirth, Phone, +@COLUMNS
 FROM ((SELECT Name, DayOfBirth, Phone FROM table_CTE) x
       PIVOT(
             MAX(Name)
             FOR Phone IN (@COLUMNS)
       ))p '
```

This is what I need:

[image]

Comment: Alberto Iznaga Marin - Welcome to StackOverflow! We'd love to help you out but can you please read the following post regarding how to ask questions on StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?

Comment: but what do you need help in this is just a query that has a dynamic value in it. where are you stuck here?

Comment: Your question is lacking a question.

Comment: Thanks for the status report.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

Edited to create nested dynamic as I didn't include the @COLUMNS In the dynamic SQL before.

Notice how the @COLUMNS variable is concatenated to the SQL.

I changed the query to select *, but you can add the @COLUMNS variable in the same way there if needed

Also in your example you have your CTE spelled table_CTE and then as tableCTE without the underscore.

```
 DECLARE @query nvarchar(4000)
 SET @query =
   'DECLARE @COLUMNS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''[CELL], [OFFICE]'';
    DECLARE @query2 NVARCHAR(4000) = ''
    WITH table_CTE ([Name], DayOfBirth, Phone) AS
    (
      SELECT pp.FirstName AS Name 
            ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(5), pp.Birthday, 103) AS Birthday            
            ,ph.Number
      FROM People pp, Phones ph
          ,PhoneNumberTypes pht 
      WHERE pp.PersonId = ph.PersonId AND ph.PhoneTypeId = pht.PhoneTypeId 
            AND MONTH(pp.Birthday) = 06
     )
     SELECT *
     FROM (SELECT [Name], DayOfBirth,Phone FROM table_CTE) x
       PIVOT(
             MAX(Name)
             FOR Phone IN ('' + @COLUMNS + '')
        )p''

     EXEC(@query2)'
    EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but that doesn't work for me either... i've updated my code and still get out of scope error for @columns variable inside pivot clause. any advice??

Comment: I modified the code to move the @COLUMNS declaration inside the dynamic SQL. notice how the dynamic SQL builds it's own dynamic SQL and executes it.. does this work any better?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but trying your and changing SELECT * for (SELECT [Name], DayOfBirth, @COLUMNS) gives me and unknown column name error for all ( Name, Phone) but DayOfBirth and @COLUMNS. I don't know why since they are in the same scope.  `